# Unique least square solutions

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra, least-squares

There is a theorem in my book that states: If $A$ is $m\times n$, then the equation $Ax = b$ has a unique least square solution for each $b$ in $\mathbb{R}^m$.

But can we find a counter-example to this by providing a matrix $A$ and vector $b$ such that $A^TAx = A^Tb$ produces a general solution with a free variable?

Comment: You're correct: if $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ with $m>n$ and the rank of $A$ is less than $n$, then the least squares problem has a solution which is not unique. The projection is unique, however. That is, any solution to the problem is mapped to the same vector by $A$.

Comment: It depends in part on what a "least squares solution" means.  There is indeed a (unique) solution $x$ of least 2-norm that minimizes the 2-norm of the error $||Ax-b||$, whatever the rank or dimensions of $A$.

Comment: Perhaps if you cited your book (author, title, edition), someone could clarify the context for you.

Comment: You must, of course, stress the "least 2-norm" part. Otherwise simple things like $A=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$ provide counterexamples.

Answer (score 7):

Of course you can have non-unique solution when $A$ has a null space. The point of least square solution is to find the orthogonal projection of $b$ in the image space of $A$. When columns of $A$ becomes linearly dependent, you can always find more than one, in fact infinitely many, solution.

Answer (score 1):

Your theorem statement is incomplete. Requirements have been omitted.

To amplify the insights of @Troy Woo, given a matrix $\mathbf{A}\in\mathbb{C}^{m \times n}$, a solution vector $x\in\mathbb{C}^{n}$, and a data vector $b\in\mathbb{C}^{m}$ such that $b\notin\mathcal{N}(\mathbf{A}^{*})$, and where $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $m\in\mathbb{N}$, the linear system
$$
\mathbf{A} x = b
$$
has the least squares solution can be expressed in terms of the Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse $\mathbf{A}^{\dagger}$:
$$
  x_{LS} = \mathbf{A}^{\dagger}b + \left(\mathbf{I}_{n} - \mathbf{A}^{\dagger}\mathbf{A} \right) y
$$
with the arbitrary vector $y\in\mathbb{C}^{n}$.

If the matrix rank $\rho < m$, the null space $\mathcal{N}\left(\mathbf{A}\right)$ is non-trivial and the projection operator $\left(\mathbf{I}_{n} - \mathbf{A}^{\dagger}\mathbf{A} \right)$ is non-zero.

**Example**

The linear system
$$
\begin{align}
  \mathbf{A} x & = b \\
%
  \left[
    \begin{array}{cc}
      1 & 0 
    \end{array}
  \right]
%
  \left[
    \begin{array}{c}
      x_{1} \\
      x_{2}
    \end{array}
  \right]
%
&=
%
  \left[
    \begin{array}{c}
      b_{1} 
    \end{array}
  \right]
\end{align}
$$
has the least squares solution
$$
\begin{align}
   x_{LS} & = \mathbf{A}^{\dagger} b + \left( \mathbf{I}_{2} - \mathbf{A}^{\dagger} \mathbf{A}\right) y\\
%
&=
%
  \left[
    \begin{array}{c}
      b_{1} \\
      0
    \end{array}
  \right]
%
+
%
\alpha 
  \left[
    \begin{array}{c}
      0 \\
      1
    \end{array}
  \right]
\end{align}
$$
with $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}^{n}$.

The affine space of the solution satisfies
$$
\mathbf{A} \left(
  \left[
    \begin{array}{c}
      b_{1} \\
      0
    \end{array}
  \right]
%
+
%
\alpha 
  \left[
    \begin{array}{c}
      0 \\
      1
    \end{array}
  \right]
 \right) = 
%
\mathbf{A} \left(
  \left[
    \begin{array}{c}
      b_{1} \\
      0
    \end{array}
  \right]
 \right)
%
+
%
 \alpha
\mathbf{A}
\left( 
  \left[
    \begin{array}{c}
      0 \\
      1
    \end{array}
  \right]
 \right) = 
%
\mathbf{A} \left(
  \left[
    \begin{array}{c}
      b_{1} \\
      0
    \end{array}
  \right]
\right).
$$

The solution vector of least norm, 
$$\Bigg\lVert 
  \left[
    \begin{array}{c}
      b_{1} \\
      0
    \end{array}
  \right]
%
+
%
 \alpha
  \left[
    \begin{array}{c}
      0 \\
      1
    \end{array}
  \right]
\Bigg\rVert_{2}^{2}$$
corresponds to $\alpha=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Least square problem usually makes sense when m is greater than or equal to n, i.e., the system is over-determined.

Then, in order to have unique least square solution, we need matrix A to have independent columns. To cook up a counter-example, just make the columns of A dependent.