# Least squares fit for an underdetermined linear system

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, interpolation, least-squares

I want fitting my data using bicubic interpolation:
$$f(x,y)=\sum_{i=0}^{3}\sum_{j=0}^{3}a_{ij}x^iy^j$$
Let known
$$f(0, 0)=1; f(2, 0)=1;f(1, 1)=0;f(0, 2) = 1; f(2, 2)=1$$
I used least squares method,
$$min\sum_{k=1}^{5}(f(x_k, y_k)-\sum_{i=0}^{3}\sum_{j=0}^{3}a_{ij}(x_k)^i(y_k)^j)^2$$
Receiving this system:
$$\forall t, s \in [0, 3]: \sum_{k=1}^{5}\sum_{i=0}^{3}\sum_{j=0}^{3}a_{ij}(x_k)^{i+t}(y_k)^{j+s} = \sum_{k=1}^{5}(x_k)^{t}(y_k)^{s}f(x_k, y_k)$$
If present as $Ax = b$:
$$A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ y_1 & y_2 & y_3 & y_4 & y_5 \\ . & . & . & . & .\\ (y_1)^3 & (y_2)^3 & (y_3)^3 & (y_4 )^3 & (y_5)^3 \\ x_1 & x_2 & x_3 & x_4 & x_5 \\ x_1 y_1 & x_2 y_2 & x_3 y_3 & x_4 y_4 & x_5 y_5 \\ x_1(y_1)^3 & x_2(y_2)^3 & x_3(y_3)^3 & x_4(y_4 )^3 & x_5(y_5)^3 \\ . & . & . & . & . \\ (x_1y_1)^3 & (x_2y_2)^3 & (x_3y_3)^3 & (x_4y_4 )^3 & (x_5y_5)^3 \end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix} 1 & y_1 & . & (y_1)^3 & x_1 & x_1y_1 & . & x_1(y_1)^3 & (x_1y_1)^3 \\ 1 & y_2 & . & (y_2)^3 & x_2 & x_2y_2 & . & x_2(y_2)^3 & (x_2y_2)^3 \\1 & y_3 & . & (y_3)^3 & x_3 & x_3y_3 & . & x_3(y_3)^3 & (x_3y_3)^3 \\ 1 & y_4 & . & (y_4)^3 & x_4 & x_4y_4 & . & x_4(y_4)^3 & (x_4y_4)^3 \\1 & y_5 & . & (y_5)^3 & x_5 & x_5y_5 & . & x_5(y_5)^3 & (x_5y_5)^3\end{pmatrix}$$ 
In my example,
$$A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 2 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 4 & 4 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 8 & 8 \\ 0 & 2 & 1 & 0 & 2 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 4 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 8 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 16 \\ 0 & 4 & 1 & 0 & 4 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 8 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 16 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 32 \\ 0 & 8 & 1 & 0 & 8 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 16 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 32 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 64 \end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 4 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 8 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 2 & 4 & 8 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 2 & 4 & 8 & 2 & 4 & 8 & 16 & 4 & 8 & 16 & 32 & 8 & 16 & 32 & 64\end{pmatrix}$$
But resulting matrix has null determinant. Please prompt me, in least squares method, coefficients matrix can be not inverted or need find mistake? Thanks!

Comment: Do I understand that you want to fit $5$ data points using $16$ parameters (the $a_{ij}$'s) ? I suppose I am wrong somewhere or that I missed a point.

Comment: It is hard to tell if even your gradient of the error is correct. The matrices look weird (hard to see if that $A$ is fine, where is $b$?). Tracing this step by step needs more time than I have. I suggest to start with a smaller instance of the problem and fix that one first then scale up.

Comment: The 16 parameters are for the bicubic. One would expect at least 16 equations to nail them down to a unique solution. I wonder too what the five unknown components of $x$ from $Ax=b$ are.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici it is just a sample, in main task I have few hundreds of points. Number on points influenced only on coefficients in matrix A. 16 parameters for accuracy of surface.

Comment: @mvw thanks, I try find mistake, matrix really tangled. Do not tell, least squares method always have single solution or not necessarily?

Comment: Oh, thanks, now I see you, my example really have small amount of control points, for 5 points I need select another degree, for degree 3 and 2 I have zero determinant, for 1 (a00, a10, a01, a11) all right. Thank a lot! It solved my problem

Comment: @Dmitry: Existence and uniqueness: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/901484/unique-least-square-solutions/2170702#2170702

Answer (score 1):

The exact solution we recover and the property of completeness suggest   transcription errors in the problem statement. The following derivation is merely a guess at the original problem.

**Problem Statement**

We start with a set of $m=5$ measurements of the form $\left\{ x_{k}, y_{k}, f_{k} \right\}_{k=1}^{m}$ and the trial function
$$
  f(x,y) = a_{00} + a_{10}x + a_{01}y + a_{20}x^{2} + a_{11}xy + a_{02}y^{2}.
$$
(Avoid notations that produce the indeterminate form $0^{0}$.) There are $n=\frac{1}{2}(d+1)(d+2)$ terms through degree $d$. (Here $d=2$.) These basis functions are *complete* through order $d$.

**Linear System**

The linear system is 
$$
\begin{align}
\mathbf{A} c &= f \\
\left[
\begin{array}{cccccc}
  1 & x_{1} & y_{1} & x_{1}^{2} & x_{1} y_{1} & y_{1}^{2} \\
  1 & x_{2} & y_{2} & x_{2}^{2} & x_{2} y_{2} & y_{2}^{2} \\
  \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
  1 & x_{m} & y_{m} & x_{m}^{2} & x_{m} y_{m} & y_{m}^{2} \\
\end{array}
\right]
%
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
  c_{00} \\
  c_{10} \\
  c_{01} \\
  c_{20} \\
  c_{11} \\
  c_{02}
\end{array}
\right]
&=
%
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
  f(x_{1},y_{1}) \\
  f(x_{2},y_{2}) \\
  \vdots \\
  f(x_{m},y_{m})
\end{array}
\right] \\
%
\left[
\begin{array}{cccccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 2 & 0 & 4 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
 1 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 4 \\
 1 & 2 & 2 & 4 & 4 & 4 \\
\end{array}
\right]
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
  c_{00} \\
  c_{10} \\
  c_{01} \\
  c_{20} \\
  c_{11} \\
  c_{02}
\end{array}
\right]
& =
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
  1 \\
  1 \\
  0 \\
  1 \\
  1 
\end{array}
\right].
\end{align}
$$
The number of rows $m=5$, the number of columns $n=6$, and the matrix rank is $\rho=5$.

**Solution**

The general least squares solution for this linear system is
$$
  c_{LS} = \mathbf{A}^{\dagger} f + \left(\mathbf{I}_{n} - \mathbf{A}^{\dagger} \mathbf{A}  \right) \zeta
$$
with the arbitrary vector $\zeta\in\mathbb{C}^{n}$. The pseudoinverse matrix is
$$
\mathbf{A}^{\dagger} = \frac{1}{40}
\left[
\begin{array}{rrrrr}
 40 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 -30 & 2 & 40 & -2 & -10 \\
 -30 & -2 & 40 & 2 & -10 \\
 5 & 9 & -20 & 1 & 5 \\
 10 & -10 & 0 & -10 & 10 \\
 5 & 1 & -20 & 9 & 5 \\
\end{array}
\right].
$$
The affine space for the solution is
$$
  c_{LS} = 
\left[
\begin{array}{r}
   1 \\
  -1 \\
  -1 \\
   \frac{1}{2} \\
   0 \\
  \frac{1}{2}
\end{array}
\right]
+
\alpha
\left[
\begin{array}{r}
   0 \\
   2 \\
  -2 \\
  -1 \\
   0 \\
   1
\end{array}
\right]
$$
where $\alpha$ is an arbitrary complex constant. This is an exact fit: $\mathbf{A}c_{LS} - f = \mathbf{0}.$ Because we are asking for 6 parameters and providing only 5 data, we will have $n - m = 1$ vectors in the null space.

The null spaces are 
$$
\mathcal{N} \left( \mathbf{A}^{\mathrm{T}} \right) = \text{span} \left\{ 
\left[
\begin{array}{r}
   0 \\
   2 \\
  -2 \\
  -1 \\
   0 \\
   1
\end{array}
\right]
\right\},
\qquad
\mathcal{N} \left( \mathbf{A} \right) = \left\{ \mathbf{0} \right\}.
$$

The title of the question which has this answer might be "Least squares fit for an underdetermined linear system".